# Why does it imply from that, that $f=0$ almost everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

When $\int_G f=0, \forall$ open $ G$, we have that if $E\subset G$ then $\exists E \subset G$ such that $m(G \setminus E)< \epsilon$.

So, $$\int_G f=\int_E f+\int_{G \setminus E } f$$

$\int_G f=0$

$\int_{G \setminus E } f$ is arbitrarily small

Therefore, we conclude that $\int_E f=0$.

Why does it imply from that, that $f=0$ almost everywhere??

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/326749/8157).

Comment: Got something from an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Because the fact that $\displaystyle\int_Ef=0$ for every $E=[nf\geqslant1]$ and for every $E=[nf\leqslant-1]$ implies that $\mu(nf\geqslant1)=\mu(nf\leqslant-1)=0$ for every $n$, which, by countable union, implies that $\mu(f\ne0)=0$.

For example, if $E=[nf\geqslant1]$ then $0=n\displaystyle\int_Ef\geqslant\mu(E)$ hence $\mu(E)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to like this approach better:

We can take a sequence of open sets $G_n$ such that $E \subset G_{n+1} \subset G_n$ for all $n$ and $m(G_n \setminus E) < 1/n$.  We may then apply the monotone convergence theorem to find that
$$
\int_E f = \int f 1_E = \int\lim_{n \to \infty} f1_{G_n} = 
\lim_{n \to \infty}  \int f1_{G_n} = 
\lim_{n \to \infty}  \int_{G_n} f = 0
$$

---

Suppose that we have an $f$ such that $\int_E f= 0 $ for all $0$.  We note by Markov's inequality that for all integers $n$, 
$$
0 = \int_{\{f > 1/n\}} f  \geq \frac 1n m(\{f > 1/n\})
$$
That is, $m(\{f \geq 1/n\}) = 0$ for all $n$.  Thus, we have
$$
m(\{f >0\}) = m \left(\bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} \{f \geq 1/n\}\right) = 0
$$
Thus, we have $f \leq 0$ except on a set of measure zero.  We therefore deduce that $-f \leq 0$ except on a set of measure zero.  Thus, 
$$
m(\{f \neq 0\}) = m(\{f > 0\} \cup \{f < 0\}) = 0
$$
as desired.

Comment: But how do we get $f=0$ almoost everywhere?? I got stck right now...

Comment: Sorry about that.  This is a well known theorem, I'll post the proof in a second.

Comment: See my latest edit.