# Integral of $f$ vanishes for generating set implies $f=0$ almost everywhere?

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a measure space and $f: X \to \mathbb R$ be $L^1$ such that for a certain subset $B \subset\mathcal A$ we have
$$\int_A f d\mu = 0$$
for all $A \in B$. If we further assume $X\in B$ and that $B$ generates the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$ can we infer that
$$\int_A f d\mu = 0$$
for all $A \in \mathcal A$ (which would be equivalent to $f=0$ $\mu$-almost everywhere)?

**Edit:** In the comments we solved the case in which $B$ is closed under finite intersections (a so called $\pi$-system). So the case where $B$ is not closed under intersection is still open. Is there maybe a counter example? Probably already
$$f:[0,4] \to \mathbb R, \quad f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$$
is a counter example. Consider all measurable subsets at which the integral vanishes. I can imagine that this already generates the sigma-algebra.

Comment: Please don’t reuse variables A,B in the same statement. What have you tried?

Comment: @Eric What do you mean by "don't reuse"?

Comment: @Eric Since the generation of sigma algebras is much more complicated than simply using countable unions and intersections, I don't know how to attack this problem.

Comment: If $B$ is closed under finite intersections then this is true by Monotone Class Theorem.

Comment: You use italics A for a sigma algebra, B as a set of sets and A as a set. This makes it hard to read. as a element of one such subset. This makes it hard to read. You can apply induction using the generators - show that complementing and countable unions still keep the integral as 0.

Comment: @Eric What you say is trivial. But that's not enough to get the whole sigma algebra back. You need transfinite induction to do that.

Comment: No? It’s just by definition of generating a sigma algebra. Let $C$ be the set of all such $A$ which give the zero integral. You can show that $C$ is closed under complements/ countable unions, and has $X$, so it’s a sigma algebra. $C$ is a sigma algebra containing $B$, so it contains the sigma algebra generated by $B$ which is $\mathcal{A}$, so anything in this gives 0 upon integrating.

Comment: To expand on Eric's comment, the only hard part of his proof is showing that the union of sets with zero integral also has zero integral.  You can use induction for the finite unions then the dominated convergence theorem to get that the entire union is zero.

Comment: @Eric I guess what you say is not enough. Consider for example the function $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$ on the interval $[0,10]$. Now collect all sets at which the integral vanishes. Then you have there for sure $[0,2]$ and $[1,3]$. But not the intersection $[1,2]$. In other words the set of all those sets forms a Dynkin system. But this Dynkin system does not have to be closed under intersection.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Now I see how (without your theorem). If $B$ was closed under intersection it would be a $\pi$-system. The set of all sets at which the integral vanishes is a Dynkin system $D$ containing $B$. Hence, the sigma-algebra generated by $B$ is contained in $D$ by Dynkin's $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem. So we are done.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Right. In my earlier comment I wanted to say $\pi -\lambda$ theorem and I said Montone CLass Theorem by mistake.

Comment: [Does this answer the question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/326862/8157)

Comment: Yes, my thing only works if $B$ is closed under intersection. Here’s a counter example when $B$ is not closed under intersection. Let $X=\{0,1,2,3\}$, $f(0)=1,f(1)=-1,f(2)=1,f(3)=-1$  Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the power set of $X$.  Let $\mu$ give weight 1 to each point. Let $B=\{\{0,1\}, \{1,2\}, \{2,3\},\{0,1,2,3\}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f \in L^1(X)$ and suppose it has zero integral on the basis for the sigma algebra.  If $f \neq 0$ a.e. then there is a measurable set $A$ with positive measure so that $f \neq 0$ on $A$.  Wlog we will assume that $f>0$ on (possibly a subset of $A$ with positive measure) A.  Now, since $B$ generates the sigma algebra there is a $B_0\in B$ with $\mu(B_0 \triangle A)< \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$.  Now let $\delta=\int_A f >0$ and pick a bounded function $|g| \leq M$ such that $|\int_A (f-g) d \mu|< \epsilon$.  Then we have

$\int_A f = \int_{B_0}f + \int_{A \cap B_0^c}(f-g)+\int_{A \cap B_0^c}(g) \leq 0+\epsilon+M \epsilon$.  If we let $\epsilon< \frac{\delta}{M+1}$ then we get a contradiction.